# Can 'at' command keep on working after ssh connection broke?

Tags: linux, ssh, at

I'm using ssh to connect to a remote server. And I execute

```
at 03:13Jun12 -f t.sh
```

would the remote host run this 't.sh' at 03:13 Jun 12 even if I broke this ssh connection? ( Assume the remote host is keep on running.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it would. The at command places the script in a file in `/var/spool/cron/atjobs`, which regularly get checked by the `atd` daemon.

Comment: If this command need superuser authority. Will it have effect if I add a sudo at the beginning of at command?

Comment: The `at` command has a [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bit set so when you run it as a normal user it runs as user `daemon` (on Debian): `-rwsr-sr-x 1 daemon daemon 46556 jun  9  2012 /usr/bin/at
`. The `/var/spool/cron/atjobs` directory is also owned by user `daemon`.

Comment: So this means whatever I use normal user or root user to run an 'at' command, the system will execute it at the specific time?

Comment: Yes, but it will run it as the user who created the at job.

Comment: I saw it. I run it as root. By the way, it will be execute at the exact file path where I run the 'at' command?

Comment: That depends on your distro. Debian `at` automatically adds a `cd` just before the command. Check the file created in `/var/spool/cron/atjobs` or the manual for your distribution.